# How long would a 5v battery power supply run a 5v LED strip for

Tags: power-supply, led, batteries, led-strip

I have an LED strip which requires a 5v input, to run from a portable power supply. The power supply has a capacity of 2200mAh with maximum output of 1A.

How long would the power supply be able to power the LED's before it needed replacing?

Comment: I can't answer this question. What does the LED strip require?

Comment: Edited. Forgot to mention it needs a 5v input.

Comment: Need either the wattage or the current it takes too though. It will run till the end of time at 5V if it takes no current.

Comment: I have a car that has a 15 gallon gas tank. How far can I drive it before it runs out of gas?

Comment: Power is 4.6W current 1A

Comment: Assuming a usb power bank? Or actually a AA battery converter?

Comment: It's a Usb power bank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the led strip takes the max of 1A it will be 2.2hours (2200mah/1000ma)

If the led strip is less that 1A use the above equation.

However, 2200ma will be rated at a particular load factor. Actual times may vary.

Comment: It does use the maximum. Just needed a reasonable idea. Thanks!

Comment: @Stommo, if this answer helped you, please consider up-voting it or accepting it.